# Method OnClick - ASP.NET Core - razor page

Tags: html, asp.net-core, html-select, razor-pages

I have a button with a `<a>` tag and in this tag I've defined a method for the `onclick`. That event is calling a script. I want to change my tag to `<Select>` and in this tag we can't use `onclick` - how can I use `onclick` in select tag and call that script?

in my project I want when click the  tag get record Id and get value of that Id
i want when i click the select (black area) get Id record Red area and get all record value from table

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjBGJ.png

```
<a href="#" id="Usernm2" name="id"  
   onclick="getSddIdW(@item.Id)" 
   data-target="#ModalSend" data-toggle="modal" class="AllIcon " 
   data-placement="tooltip" title="">
    <i class="btn bg-primary-bright"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo to use onclick in  `<Select>`, you can refer to it.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@functions{
    public string GetHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}


<select id="TypeOfUser" name="typeOfUser" class="active text-normal" 
                                       Onclick="RazorFunction()">
    <option value="2" >CMS Users</option>
    <option value="3">Site Users</option>
</select>

<button> aa</button>

@section Scripts
{
 <script>
    function RazorFunction() {
        $("button").html('@GetHello()');
    }

 </script>
}
```

result:
[image]

But I suggest you use  `onchange` in  `<Select>`.

result:

[image]